# How to connect to a Summit switch via PuTTy using a RJ45-DB9 cable

Tags: switch

I have the following:

- Windows 7
- Putty .66
- RJ45-DB9

I have been out of the networking field for quite sometime (10 years) and I forgot how to console into a switch.

Do I need to configure my PC interface with an IP address?

Do I select serial/ssh/telnet for my connection on PuTTy?

If someone would be able to provide a step-by-step "guide" I'd appreciate it very much.

Comment: My Summit 400-48t has a db-9 serial,  and so needs a null modem serial cable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Summit switches (I have tried Cisco switches)

So if your switch has Console port (usually they need either serial cable or RJ45)

Im gonna assume it's RJ45. Your RJ45 cable ends with serial end just like in this picture: 
[image]

You plug the RJ45 into the switch. The other end needs to go to your computer. If you're computer has serial port input, great.. If not, then you will need a good quality serial to USB cable.

Go to your device manager on your computer and find out what COM number you have.

Take a look at my attachment. 
[image]

In my computer it's COM9, open putty and follow the attachment picture.

Comment: Unfortunately, product or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic here. I edited the question to remove the product recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

You'll also need a USB to serial adapter if you computer has no serial interface. Choose serial in putty and 9600 baud, 8 data bits, no parity and 1 stop bit (96008n1).

You can only use ssh/telnet if you device has an IP address and is configured correctly.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

here's an exampling using putty with COM9... You COM number might be different. if it's 3, then put 3 in putty (COM3)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.instructables.com/id/Cisco-Console-to-Null-Modem-Serial-Adapter/

u need this first ....

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Not sure how converting a Cisco console cable into a null modem serial adapter applies. Or are you saying that Summit gear requires a null modem serial cable?